# Execute an rspec stub at runtime instead of at stub declaration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2

Let's say I needed to stub a method so it returned the current time:
MyClass.stub(:my_method).and_return(Time.now.utc)

The problem is, this stub returns the time at stub declaration, not when I run MyClass.new.my_method.

Is there any way to make a stub run when the method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in a block to `and_return` that does the work you want done at runtime, like so...

```
describe MyClass do

  it "runs at runtime" do
    puts Time.now.utc

    MyClass.stub(:my_method).and_return do
      Time.now.utc
    end
    sleep 5.seconds

    puts MyClass.my_method
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For an instance method I was able to do this adding a block after the receive

```
allow_any_instance_of(MyClass)
  .to receive(:method_name) do
    executed_at_runtime
  end.and_return(result_to_return)
```